# Android Studio failed to initialize Vuforia

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, augmented-reality, vuforia

[SOLVED - See answer below]

---

I am new to mobile development and I am currently working on an Android Studio project which requires some dependencies to run a VR simulation developed on a proprietary game engine. A while ago, the company of this game engine created an Android app on Eclipse which works and actually runs their simulations. I am trying to import the libraries and classes I need in my project but I am facing many issues. I have spent quite a few hours on the last one which involves Vuforia.

```
Error - failed to assert required Android permissions. Failed to initialize QCAR SDK. All required Android permissions must be included for the SDK to work.  
InitVuforiaTask.onPostExecute: Failed to initialize Vuforia. Exiting.  
EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1  
STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.company.myproject
```

My .so libraries get loaded from my src/main/jniLibs folder and my .jar libraries are loaded from my src/main/libs folder.

The Eclipse project I am using as a model is targeting Android API 19 and its min sdk version is 15. When I import it in Android Studio (2.3.1), it runs on my test device.

Permissions included in my manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I tried to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

... but it didn't change anything. This is my app Gradle:

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('src/main/libs/BT200Ctrl.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/NativeMediaPlayer.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/Net.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/Sensors.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/VoIP.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/portsipvoipsdk.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/Vuforia.jar')
}
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

---

### Answer

[Kevin Sanchez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386595/vuforia-sdk-android-failed-to-initialize-vuforia-with-permission-exception/43480446#43480446) solved my problem.

Before launching the activity using Vuforia, we need to ask for the camera permission explicitly (this is a requirement for newest API versions).

Instead of launching the activity using Vuforia directly, I inserted the following statement:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VuforiaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the activity asking for the camera permission, we need to listen to the user's answer with:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VuforiaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_permission_needed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/43480446/5335153

Comment: It worked, thanks! I only took "grantResults[1]" off the if statement to make my code work :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 to 3 reasons why this error occurs:
Checklist:

- SDK missing
- license key is missing
- gradle file is not updating for loading SDK from libs folder in app